# Copy data from one sheet to another; creating a table with the copied data in the target sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find a script where I can copy data from a spreadsheet in specific cells, then paste it in a different tab *within the same spreadsheet.*

Once the info is copied and pasted, I will run a script to erase the data in the SOURCE tab, so new info can be typed in. (I already have the code for erasing)

```
function EraseInfo() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SOURCE');
  sheet.getRange('B2').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('C4').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D6').clearContent();
}
```

The idea is that a table could be generated on the **TARGET sheet** with the information entered in the **SOURCE sheet**.

Example:

I want to copy cells B2, C4 and D6 from the SOURCE sheet to cells B2, B3 and B4 in the TARGET sheet, respectively. 
Then on the second instance the copied data should be pasted in the SOURCE sheet, but in cells C2, C3 and C4, and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first put the data from your SOURCE sheet into an array. Then send it through to the range you want on TARGET sheet.

This is one way to do it, I am fairly new to programming, so there might be a better way.

I assumed you had data in TARGET sheet on A2,A3, and A4.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SOURCE')
  var tSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('TARGET')
  var SourceD = sSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var SourceArray = [[SourceD[1][1]],[SourceD[3][2]],[SourceD[5][3]]]
  var LastC = tSheet.getLastColumn()
  tSheet.getRange(2, LastC+1,3).setValues(SourceArray)  
}
```

This should get you started. This script is putting all data on the SOURCE sheet into an array, then it is picking out what it needs. After this you just need to insert `EraseInfo()` at the end of this function, and once it has copied the data over, it will erase the information on the SOURCE sheet.

Again there are many ways to do this, this is the one I would use.

**EDIT: Answer to comment below**

You would have to change the three bottom lines of code to do so. This is the easy way, and assumes you have the same data for A and B columns, and have titles in at least A1. You would put in whatever data you needed for columns A and B in `"Data A"` and `"Data B"`

```
function myFunction() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SOURCE')
  var tSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('TARGET')
  var SourceD = sSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var SourceArray = [["Data A", "Data B",SourceD[1][1],SourceD[3][2],SourceD[5][3]]]
  var LastR = tSheet.getLastRow()
  tSheet.getRange(LastR+1, 1,1,5).setValues(SourceArray)  
}
```

Comment: How should I change the code if I wanted to get the info gathered by row instead of columns? (as it currently is). e.g. Take the info from the same place in SOURCE, but get it to TARGET in C2, D2 and E2. @bryce